# Solving for running time

Tags: algorithm, iteration, big-o

Please can someone give me a direction as to how to solve the running time of:
T(n) = nT(n-1) + O(n^2)?

I know that T(n) = nT(n-1) => T(n) = O(n!)
But how to I solve it with the extra O(n^2)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homework?  Regardless, it depends.  If you're looking for the Big-O time, the O(n^2) doesn't add anything.  O(N!) consumes O(N^2), for almost all values of N.  Or rather, for values of N > 3, N! > N^2.  You can also show it like this.  N! + 16 > N^2 for all N.

Or, you can compute the combined computation time like this

```
T(N) = N! + N^3.

T(N) = nT(n-1) + n^2
T(N) = (n - 1)T(n-2) + n^2 + (n-1)^2
T(N) = (n-2)(n-1)T(n-2) + n^2 + (n-1)^2 + (n-2)^2
T(N part 1) = 1 * 2 * 3 ... * n = n!
T(N part 2) = 1 + 4 + 9 ... + n^2 = (1/3)n3 + (1/2)n2 + (1/6)n

T(N) = n! + (1/3)n^3 + (1/2)n^2 + (1/6)n
T(N) = n! + n^3
T(N) = n!
```

The answer is one of the three bottom lines, depending on the level of granularity we want with respect to big-O.  I like the middle one because it acknowledges the polynomial complexity, while obviously leaving n! as the primary concern, without overly complicating the answer.

Comment: Sure, O(n^2) is consumed by O(n!), but the computation time is not, simply, T(N) = N! + N^2, its T(N) = nT(n-1)+n^2. The fact T(n) = nT(n-1) equates to N! does not mean you can simply substitute it. Regardless, I think N! is the correct answer, I just don't think your explanation is valid.

Comment: @AYR: "If you're looking for Big-O time."

Comment: I covered both bases man... the portion of the explanation you were referencing I had immediately prefixed with "If you're looking for Big-O time" I then provided the answer if you weren't. "Or, you can compute the combined computation time like this".  Alternatively, you could try specifying.

Comment: But by that logic I could say that T(n) = T(n-1) + n = n + n = O(n), couldn't I? But the answer is O(n^2)... I just don't follow the substitution you performed on the last line of your original answer...

Comment: The substitution doesn't work. Solve for T(n) = nT(n-1) + an^2 + b.

Comment: My appologies I think there was a typo in my original answer, it should have been n! + n^3.  I fixed it, with some additional work.